# Error everytime I submit this to the database from my flask app

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask, wtforms

This is using the Flask framework, I am getting this error when I try to send the data to the database I created via sqlite.  Here is my database model, as well as the form model.

```
firstname = StringField('First Name', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=2, max=30)])
    lastname = StringField('Last Name', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=2, max=30)])
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=40)])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=40)])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[InputRequired(), Email(message='Invalid Email'), Length(max=120)])
```

That is the wtforms form data, here is the database model:

```
class usersTable(db.Model):
    userid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fname = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    lname = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.LargeBinary, unique=True, nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.LargeBinary, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.LargeBinary, nullable=False)
```

For some reason, when I send this I get this server error.  It keeps saying that it needs to be bytes and not a 'str'?  Can someone shed some light on this

error:

```
a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: Your email, username, and password fields should be `db.String` not `db.LargeBinary`

Comment: Thank you!  This done it, submit it as an answer and I will definitely check it!

Comment: You're welcome. Added answer. Happy coding to you.

Comment: emails, username can't be binary value mate, it should be string only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your email, username, and password fields should be `db.String`